# How to remove anchor link's dotted focus outlines only for mouse events but not for keyboard tabbed navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

For anchor links i want to removes the dotted focus outlines for mouse events, but want to display them when for keyboard tabbed navigation.? Is there any javascript, jquery method?

Method should be compatible all A-grade browsers. including IE6.

Although all pure css methods to remove dotted lines do not works in IE 6.

But remember i want to remove dotted focus outlines **only for mouse events**, but want to display them when user use keyboard tabbed navigation.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Curious as to why you wouldn't want them looking the same if they're treated the same...

Comment: on mouse events dotted lines looks ugly but it's needed on keyboard access and mostly people use mouse so i just want to remove outlines for mouse users

Comment: But on mouse events the outline helps the user see what they clicked on, much like it helps a keyboard user see what they pressed Enter on.

Comment: yes u r right but i need to do this thing for a client website bcoz client want this. and nothing is important than client, whatever usability, accessibility, web standards etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove focus onmousedown in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205653/how-do-i-remove-focus-onmousedown-in-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use jQuery/Javascript to apply style when **mouseover**. That way `outline:none;` will **must likely to apply** when it's a mouse click.

CSS:

```
.foo.bar:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".foo").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("bar");
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("bar");
    });
});
```

**Unfortunately**, this brings another problem: IE6 compaitability with multiple classes. This can be solved by using double div techniques to apply style with multiple classes.

Comment: @Jitendra, `.bar` means another class name, it can be any name of your choice. the name choice `foo` and `bar` have no meaning itself.

Comment: You can use `element.hideFocus=true` in IE.

Comment: The problem with this method is that it only removes the outline while the mouse is within (hovering over) the element with .foo

Answer (score 0):

While I understand the OP wanted to handle IE6 as well, I've posted this solution for anyone is not concerned with IE6 and who wants to allow keyboard navigation (focus rectangles still appear when tab is pressed) but hide the focus rectangle when the element is clicked (or enter key is pressed).

The .hide-focus-on-click is just a jQuery selector - replace it with whatever selector you need (e.g. "div#nav a" for all hyperlinks within )

CSS:

```
.no-focus-rectangle {
    outline: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hide-focus-on-click").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("no-focus-rectangle");
    }).blur(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("no-focus-rectangle");
    });
});
```